# Creating a separate log for each Passenger process in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, logging, passenger

I'm trying to determine the cause of high app server instance memory usage and to do so I need a separate log for each running Passenger process (e.g., production_18204.log). Is there a simple way to configure this in a Rails app? Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Found something?

Answer (score 0):

To log memory used by process in each request use the following code.

```
def log_memory_usage
  mem_usage = `ps -o rss= -p #{ Process.pid }`.to_i
  if logger
    logger.info("[MEMORY USAGE]: #{ number_to_human_size(mem_usage) } | PID: #{ Process.pid } | CONTROLLER: #{ controller_name } | ACTION: #{ action_name }")
  end
end
```

Use this as before action in your base or application controller. Do include `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` to make `number_to_human_size` work.

Courtesy: https://github.com/binarylogic/memorylogic